# Is $\displaystyle X=\frac{\mathbb R^2\sqcup\{*\}}{S^1\sqcup \{*\}}$ homeomorphic to $S^2\vee S^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{*\}$ be a discrete unit space. Consider the quotient space: $$X=\frac{\mathbb R^2\sqcup\{*\}}{S^1\sqcup \{*\}}.$$ I have two questions concerning this space:

(a) Is $X\simeq S^2\vee S^2$?

(b) If $(a)$ does not hold, is $X$ homeomorphic to some other familiar space?

Thanks!

Comment: By "discrete unit space," do you mean a single point? When you take the union $\mathbb{R}^2 \sqcup \{ \ast \}$, what is the resulting topology?

Comment: How do you define that quotient?

Comment: If you mean the one point compactification with $\infty$ then (a) is correct. If it just means the disjoint union the result would be $\mathbb{R^2}/S^1 \cong S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^2$. You can see this, by regarding everything as CW complexes and collapsing a part of the 1-skeleton. Or just compute it by hand.

Comment: Yes @PhillipAndreae I mean $\{*\}$ is a set with a single element. As to the topology, $U\subset X\sqcup \{*\}$ is open if and only if the pre-image of every injection is open. The quotient topology is the usual..

Comment: Yes @DanValenzuela I mean the one point copactification =D

Comment: The one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$. If you then collapse $S^1$ (which you can think of as an equator of the $S^2$), you obtain $S^2 \vee S^2$. But if, as your question states, you collapse both $S^2$ and the point at infinity, you obtain $S^2 \vee S^2$ with a point on one of the $S^2$'s identified with the point where the $S^2$'s are attached to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Answer (a) is correct.

Take for $\mathbb{R^2}\cup \infty$ the CW structure consisting of 1 0-cell, 1 1-cell (namely the $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \subset \mathbb{R^2}\cup \infty$ and finally two 2-cells (disks) glued by the identity onto the 1-skeleton. This is the 2-sphere $\mathbb{R^2}\cup \infty$ (being a little bit redundant here)

Now if we denote $X^n$ to be the n-skeleton, then you are precisely asking for the space $X^2/X^1$ but we now that for CW complexes, this is just a wedge of spheres (as many as 2-cells)

hope it helps

Comment: but note that this is the space $R^2\cup \infty / S^1$. If you really want also to divide by the not connected subset joined with infinity you get a  2-torus with collapsed meridian and a sphere attached at this singularity.

Comment: Indeed I was looking for the one point compactification of $\mathbb R^2\setminus S^1$, but I'm not finding the right arguments for doing this..